# Can't access a schema model id when referenced inside another schema (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I am building a website using mongodb and mongoose for the database, and so far I have 2 schema models: a User model and a Coach model. Each user can create a Coach profile. Following are the Schema definitions:

// Coach Schema definition

```
var CoachSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nom:String,
    prenom:String,
    email:String,
    description:String,
    author:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }],
    photo:String,
    password:String,

})

var Coach=mongoose.model("Coach", CoachSchema);
```

And the User Schema definition (saved inside model file and required on the same document where Coach schema is defined, like this: var User=require("./models/user"))

//User Schema definition inside of ./model/user

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        username:String,
        password:String,
    },
    facebook:{
        id:String,
        token:String,
        email:String, 
        name:String,
    }

});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports=mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

The problem I am having is that when a user creates a new coach profile, the author array is empty like this:

```
{ 
  __v: 0,
  nom: 'John ',
  prenom: 'Smith',
  email: 'js@gmail.com',
  description: 'blabla blabla',
  photo: '',
  password: '',
  _id: 5981a27926249b2118726578,
  **author: []** 
}
```

Does anyone please has any idea how I can fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Do you pass user id in author array when creating coach?

Comment: What do you mean Talha Awan? Normally, what I expect, is to automatically have user id inside of the author array, but it is empty.

Comment: That's not how it works. You need to pass in the id yourself.

Comment: ok, but isn't that what I did @TalhaAwan with this piece of code :    author:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }],

Comment: No, that's schema definition, as is `description: String`. It only tells what is expected as input. What you put in the field at creation time should match the definition.

Comment: Thank you @TalhaAwan, I fixed it using what you told me.